# can I declare an array where one of the array elements is undeclared variable? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, declaration

```
#input_from_the_net = ""

my_array = [ ["Header name" , input_from_the_net] ]

input_from_the_net = "a value scraped from the net"

puts "#{my_array[0][0]} is #{my_array[0][1]}"
```

### EDIT:

I use the variable `input_from_the_net` later on in the loop and assign its value into a hash. That hash is then stored inside another hash. If I use `input_from_the_net.replace("a value scraped from the net")` it replaces the value inside all hashes. That is not desired. I want all hashes to keep the correct values.

### EDIT2: more detailed sample code

```
`require 'pp'
input_from_the_net = ""

def parse_the_website()
  (0..5).each { |index| 
    input_from_the_net = index+23
    @my_hash[index] = {@my_array[0][0] => input_from_the_net}
  } 
end

@my_array = [ ["Header name" , input_from_the_net] ] 
       #my_array is used on different places of the code

@my_hash = {}
parse_the_website
pp @my_hash
```

Q1: can I make this **work and not change the order of lines**?

Q2: if I uncomment `#input_from_the_net = ""` the value of the variable input_from_the_net at the time of printing is "" not the "a value scraped from the net". How come?

Comment: You have change the intent of the question considerably. Can you post a new code example to show the problem?

Comment: @Doug Neiner: I thought that `my_array = [ ["Header name" , input_from_the_net] ]` is the most important in my question. Maybe I simplified it too much.I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend making  a simple class:

```
class Netinput
  attr_accessor :netinput

def initialize(netinput = "")
  @netinput = netinput
end

end
```

Then use it like this:

```
input_from_the_net = "our test string"

#Netinput can take a string or no argument
my_array = [ ["Header name" , Netinput.new()] ]

my_array[0][1].netinput = input_from_the_net

puts "#{my_array[0][0]} is #{my_array[0][1].netinput}"

# Outputs: Header name is our test string
```

With this approach the second element of each array is an object that has its own instance variable "netinput."  Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: @Beanish: your answer is closer to something I am looking for. Is that possible to change the code that the line `input_from_the_net = "our test string"` won't be there and that it would follow the code structure from my question under Edit2 section? I tried that I am getting `undeclared array with object.rb:6: uninitialized constant Netinput (NameError)`. What is really important that I can use the array inside functions/procedures.

Comment: you don't need the line input_from_the_net = "our test string" that is just setting a value to that variable, however you set it I don't know.  If you remove that line my code still works because I set the instance variable to "" if no argument is given.  

If you copy and paste my two code blocks into a file and run it, it should work for you.  Then modify that to fit your means.

Comment: yes, your initial code is working fine.When modifying it I moved `my_array = [ ["Header name" , Netinput.new()] ]` before the definition of the class thinking that the order doesn't matter. Very nice solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep the same order you have, but you need to use `replace`:

```
input_from_the_net = ""

my_array = [ ["Header name" , input_from_the_net] ]

input_from_the_net.replace("a value scraped from the net")

puts "#{my_array[0][0]} is #{my_array[0][1]}"

# Outputs: Header name is a value scraped from the net
```

Every time you use `=` with a string, it creates a new string and assigns it to the variable. To replace it without creating a new string, you use the `String.replace` method.

For fun, you can use `irb` to test this out:

```
>> str = "Hello"
=> "Hello"
>> str.object_id
=> 2156902220                  # original id
>> str = "New String"
=> "New String"
>> str.object_id
=> 2156889960                  # different id
>> str.replace("Third String")
=> "Third String"
>> str.object_id
=> 2156889960                  # same id
```

Comment: that's interesting, I didn't know that about strings. And is there any way not to use `input_from_the_net = ""` at all?

Comment: You need to assign it as a string at some point, but you can do it inline: `my_array = [ ["Header name" , input_from_the_net = ""] ]` and save the previous call to initialize the variable.

Comment: the inline initialization is great.

Comment: I cannot use the .replace method. See my update in my question. I replaces all values 'backwards'.